# How to bypass the width limit of the container element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div container with the width 500px;

in this div element there are several images.

I have written a jQuery code for these images so that when a user clicks on an image, it shows a large version of it. this large version must be wrapped up with a div. Now, that div, due to its parent container, could not go more than 500px in width. I need at least 1200px width. How can overcome this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you've written?

Comment: Is using a plugin like lightbox, colorbox, etc, an option?

Comment: Try position:fixed or absolute for your large version...

Comment: no i'm not using any plugin. it is all simple jquery with simple div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to position absolute your child div element in order for it to "escape" from the parent element.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/9r7Xd/)**

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    Parent
    <div id="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:blue;}

#child {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
top:100px;
left:20px;
background-color:red;}
```

Comment: Glad i could help. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use `position: absolute` for this.

A child element with `width: 100%` fills out the entire width of the parent element. Giving it a larger width, such as `width 300%`, allows it to extend through its parent. To center it you can nudge it to the left with a negative `margin-left` (or simply with a `left`) value equal to 50% of the added width.

[Here's a pen of this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fpCqc).